# SELECT Dinamico y opcion seleccionada por defecto

Tags: php, html5, select

Soy completamente nuevo y sin nada de experiencia, indico: Como se muestra en la imagen ya realizo la consulta SQL para que me cargen los paises desde la base de datos al SELECT de mi página, ahora quiero dejar seleccionado por defecto un Pais (por ejemplo ECUADOR) como le hago para dejar seleccionado ese pais en el ciclo? Gracias (html5, php)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no pongas el código como imagen, copia y pega y usa el botón {} para darle formato de código.

Answer (score 1):

En base a tu codigo y usando una notacion alternativa para el while

```
<?php
$sql_consulta = 'SELCT * FROM pais ORDER BY nombre';
$consulta = mysqli_query($cone, $sql_consulta) or die(mysqli_errno());
?>
<select name="pais" id="pais">
    <option disabled>Selecciona un Pais</option>
    <?php while ($fila = $consulta->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <?php $atributo = ($fila['nombre'] == $nombre) ? 'selected' : '' ?>
        <option <?= $atributo ?> ><?= $fila['nombre'] ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

La linea que hace todo es esta

```
<?php $atributo = ($fila['nombre'] == $nombre) ? 'selected' : '' ?>
```

puesto que si es el valor nombre de la fila es el nombre que buscas asigna 'selected' de lo contrario asigna vacio.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="pais">
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
$pais = $row['pais'];
if($pais=='ARGENTINA'){//aqui cambia el nombre del pais que deseas
    echo '<option selected value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['pais'].'</option>';
    }else{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['pais'].'</option>';    
    }   
}
?>
</select>
```

lo modifique un poco pero seguro podras adaptarlo, ya lo acabo de probar y funciona al 100

Answer (score -1):

cambia:

```
<option selected disabled>seleccione un pais</option>
```

por

```
<option selected>Ecuador</option>
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected>Ecuador</option>
  <option>Rusia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No bro no me sale, en que parte de mi ciclo le agrego una comparativa $valor == $fila['nombre']  para que quede seleccionada este Pais, gracias